GC overhead limit exceeded while stroing data into HashMap
i'm reading multiple csv file and storing its data in a single HashMap.there are 24csv files but when 20th file data is process program is throwing exception "GC overhead limit exceeded".
i dont know how to solve it.
]


You ran out of memory. Give the JVM more memory with -Xmx command line option or rework your code to use less.

Do not post screenshots of text. Post the text. Besides that, you should close resources after use, preferably with try-with-resources. Further, you should declare variables where you need them, not miles away from that place. And this (manual) array copying loop seems to to be entirely obsolete.
